# 'g++-dw2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: c++, gcc

When I try to use gcc 4.6.2 with my qt I'm getting following error:

```
'g++-dw2' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

In Qt's pro file I have added:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
QMAKE_CXX = g++-dw2
QMAKE_LINK = g++-dw2
```

If I don't add those two lines I'm getting error: undefined reference to _unwindSomething
Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem at hand:

If `g++-dw2` is not already on your system, then you need to install it.  Then you need to add it to your path or at least tell Qt the full path to the executable.

Comment: It looks like there is a lot more info here:  http://www.qtforum.org/article/29890/qt-4-6-linking-problem.html